# Set alternating highlight colors to text in Vim?

Tags: linux, vi, vim

Is it possible to set alternating (one color for lines with odd line number and another for even line numbers) highlighting colors for each row in Vim?

Comment: Would an alternating *background* color suit you? There seem to be a script that does that in that thread: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Alternating-lines-color-td5531621.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can do what you want with text background colors:

```
syn match Oddlines "^.*$" contains=ALL nextgroup=Evenlines skipnl
syn match Evenlines "^.*$" contains=ALL nextgroup=Oddlines skipnl

hi Oddlines ctermbg=yellow guibg=#FFFF99 
hi Evenlines ctermbg=magenta guibg=#FFCCFF
```

Just add this to `.vimrc` or the right file type `.rc` you want.

Since this utilizes the `syntax` functionality, it only applies to matchable typed text. I don't know if there's a way to alternate the background color of the empty "space" after text that `hi Normal ctermgb=darkblue guibg=darkblue` does.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried putting this in a function in the .vimrc and called it and it changes the color of all rows to blue. Any ideas on where to look?

Comment: hm, could it be conflicting with something you already have? Try starting vim/gvim with `-u NONE` to load a vanilla instance and then see if it still happens.

Comment: It works when the Vim is started with "-u NONE". Thanks again!

Comment: +1 a beautiful answer and a great piece of code for introduction to the land of syntax files.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built-in, so you would have to emulate that (and suffer from the consequences like slow performance, bad interference, etc.) A candidate would be `:match` / `:call matchadd()`, because that is independent of syntax highlighting. Demo:

```
hi Alternate guibg=LightGrey guifg=NONE
execute 'match Alternate /\%(' . join(map(range(1,100), '"\\%" . v:val * 2 . "l"'), '\|') . '\)/'
```